# Except duplicated results from elastic aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my query that returns results on 19th Oct.

```
GET apachelog/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ext.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "time_zone": "Asia/Seoul",
        "gte": "2015-10-19",
        "lt": "2015-10-20"
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Below are the results.

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "NAME" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "php",
          "doc_count" : 36797
        },
        {
          "key" : "png",
          "doc_count" : 18202
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

This is second query that returns results on 18th Oct.

```
GET apachelog/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ext.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "time_zone": "Asia/Seoul",
        "gte": "2015-10-18",
        "lt": "2015-10-19"
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Below are the second results.

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "NAME" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "php",
          "doc_count" : 10885
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

And i want to except results on 18th Oct from results on 19th Oct. Below is the result i want.

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "NAME" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "png",
          "doc_count" : 18202
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Can i create query behaves like sql query below in elasticsearch?

```
select distinct(ext)
from apachelog
where @timestamp = '2015-10-19'

minus

select distinct(ext)
from apachelog
where @timestamp = '2015-10-18'
```

I'm trying to write a MINUS query use the bool query with must and must_not. This is my third query.

```
GET apachelog/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "time_zone": "Asia/Seoul",
              "gte": "2015-10-19",
              "lt": "2015-10-20"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "time_zone": "Asia/Seoul",
              "gte": "2015-10-18",
              "lt": "2015-10-19"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ext.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But can't returns the result i want. Anyone could show me the way? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: What does "I want to **except** results on 18th from results on 19th" mean? Do you want to **subtract** them? Searching for the whole of 19th is automatically excluding the docs from the 18th ...

Comment: @JoeSorocin I just want to remove duplicate data.

Comment: Duplicate by what measure? The document ID? Some other aggregatable field?

Comment: @JoeSorocin Just terms are duplicated and no other aggregatable field. I edited my post.